# Gelfand transform of space of continuous functions on compact Hausdorff space.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading Rudin's Functional Analysis 11.13 page 283 and I am confused by this example:

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, put $A = C(X)$. Let $\triangle$ denotes the set of complex homomorphisms or maximal ideals of $C(X)$. It is proven that there is a bijection between $X$ and $\triangle$, but then he goes on to say that this implies the Gelfand transform is the identity mapping on $C(X)$. I do not understand this statement. The Gelfand transform sends $A$ to $\hat{A}$, which are complex homomorphisms on $\triangle$. To me, this is not the same as $C(X)$.

Comment: Right, that is proven in the book: he proved that there is a bijection between $\triangle$ and $X$. But what I do not understand is given $a \in C(X)$, $\hat{a}$ is a map from $\triangle \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, how can you identify $\hat{a}$ with $C(X)$

Comment: Every complex homomorphism is of the form $\varphi_{x_0}(f)=f(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in X.$ The Gelfand transform is given by $\hat{f}(\varphi_x)=\varphi_x(f)=f(x).$ So it is the identity map. You just identify $x$ with $\varphi_x.$

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thank you very much.